# Listening to HTML content change inside a WebView

Tags: android, android-webview, mopub

I'm building a 3rd party library in Android that works on WebViews and analyzes their performance.

From the work done so far, I found that some Ad servers bring up Banner ad WebViews, and auto-refreshes the ad every X seconds.

During the auto-refresh, I noticed they replace the HTML content with a new ad, rather than creating a new WebView instance.

**I need to catch these reloads without interfering with JS injections.**

I would expect to have some kind of a *setOnDomChangedEventListener* method, but I couldn't find one.

What technique can I use to catch these events?

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, reloads and DOM changes are different things. A page can change DOM without loading anything. A reload of a page re-initializes DOM and JS context from scratch, so it's not the same as a dynamic update of the DOM tree.

If you want to listen to network loads, you need to use `WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest` callback in WebView.

Listening to DOM changes is not possible via WebView Java API. One way to do that is to inject your code into the page and use `MutationObserver` [(doc)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). Just be aware that if the page reloads, you will need to re-inject the code.

A less intrusive but more involved way is to use remote Web Debugging. The debugging protocol WebView uses supports [DOM breakpoints](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/protocol/1.1/domdebugger). Actually, if you are building a performance analyzing framework, that might be a good approach, as it will allow you to measure and monitor lots of things. But be aware that due to security considerations, in order for an Android app to connect to the remote debugging socket, it needs to run either as `shell` user (as `adb`), or be signed with the same key as the target app.